# 2 jQuery events on same action seem to cancel each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

**Update: I have pasted working code in order to erase any ambiguity about what is going on. I have also tried to remove the preventDefault on both handlers, does not help*

I have a form where upon the button click, a JS event needs to happen, and the form needs to submit.

As per the code below, what I thought would happen is: alert(button), then alert(form), or vice versa. **I do not care about sequence.**

If i run it however, the alert(button) will show up, but the alert(form) will not.

If i comment out the code for the button, the form alert comes up.

Do i have some fundamental misunderstanding of how this is supposed to work?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $("form.example").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("form submitted");
  });


  $("form.example button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("button clicked");
  });
)};


<form class="example" action="/v4test">
  <button type="submit">Meow!</button>  
</form>
```

Comment: click event function of "'$('form button').click { // does some action}'" returns false?

Comment: @Kranu - To be more precise: `.submit { ...` should be `.submit(function() { ... });` and `.click { ...` should be `.submit(function() { ... });` ... see my answer below.

Comment: Can you paste your actual event handlers?

Comment: @kranu @peter @tge - i pasted the actual code above. If you paste it somewhere and run it, you should see exactly what i mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After edit of OP

You do not need to preventDefault of the click.... only the submit... here is you working code:

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4YUXH/)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.example').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("form submitted");
        // stop submission so we don't leave this page
    });
    $('form.example button').click(function() {
        alert("button clicked");
    });
});​
```

---

old answer

You can simply put your **[`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)** and **[`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)** handlers in series, and they should not cancel out. You have some **syntax errors** in your pseudo code.... maybe those are causing problems?

Another potential problem is that **[`$("form button")`](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)** targets the HTML `<button>` tags. If you use `<input type="button" />` you should use **[`$("form:button")`](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/)** and note that `<input type="submit" />` is **not** a button. Anyway, I'll assume you are in fact using the `<button>` tags.

Usually `return false` is used inside `.submit(function() { ... });`. This stops the form from being submited through HTML. `s**[topPropagation][6]**` is very different. It deals with stopping events "bubbling up" to the parents of elements....... But I don't see how this would effect your case.

If you are doing a true HTML submission, make sure to put your `.click()` handler first, since a true HTML submission will cause you to leave the page.

If you use `return false` inside `.submit()`, the form will not be submitted through the HTML, and you'll have to handle the submission with jQuery / Javascript / AJAX.

Anyway, here is a demonstration of both the `.click()` and `.submit()` events firing in series... the code is below:

### **[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FCUV8/)**

```
$(function() {

    $('form button').click(function() {

        // Do click button stuff here.

    });

    $('form').submit(function(){

        // Do for submission stuff here
        // ...
        // stop submission so we don't leave this page
        // Leave this line out, if you do want to leave
        // the page and submit the form, but then the results of your
        // click event will probably be hard for the user to see.
        return false;

    });

});​
```

The above will trigger **both** handlers with the following HTML:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

---

As a note, I suppose you were using pseudo code, but even then, it's much easier to read, and one is sure you're not writing syntax errors, if you use:

```
$('form').submit(function() { /*submits form*/ }); 
$('form button').click(function() { /*does some action*/ });
```

Comment: `return false` is quite different from `stopPropagation`, see my answer for details.

Comment: @Tgr - Which is why I wrote, `Usually return false is used inside .submit(function() { ... }); not stopPropagation which deals with even bubbling`... maybe I wasn't clear in my phrasing.

Comment: Hi Peter! I have pasted actual working code above. I understand your code, and I appreciate your comments, but it does not quite solve the basic problem here. Thanks a lot, and sorry for the lousy pseudo code!

Comment: @ming - Edited. Take a look. You only need one of the preventDefaults.

Comment: @peter thanks! do you mind explaining why this works? thanks a lot for your help, i am still getting around how the async works exactly

Comment: @ming - You only need to cancel the submital of the form with preventDefault. The click on the button itself doesn't need to be cancelled, since that is separate from the submit.

Comment: @peter - i see - the form was prevented from submitting BECAUSE of the preventdefault of the button. how obvious can it get. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you put a return false on the click, it should cancel the default behavior.  If you want to execute one then the other, call $('form').submit() within the click function.  e.g.

```
$('form').submit { //submits form}

$('form button').click {
// does some action
$('form').submit();
}
```

Comment: This code is formatted badly, what is `$('form').submit {` and what is `$('form button').click {` ? This code will not work at all.

Comment: They are copied from the additional example.

Comment: @Gazler - The example is wrong and won't work. This may be one of the reasons the OP is asking the question in the first place.

Comment: Hi folks! Peter is right i do not want it to execute one after the other, because the button click is a pure client action, while the form submit is a ajax action => so i can have both execute at the same time. Secondly, the button click behavior is universal, which means it can affect many forms/scenarios. So i do not want to tie it down un-neccessarily to any given actions

Comment: btw, the example is just a pseduo code, i will take more care to write proper code =)

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood the question then.  Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Does clicking the button submit the form? If so:

```
// Disable the submit action
$("form").submit(function(){
    return false; 
});

$("form button").click(function(){
    // Do some action here

    $("form").unbind("submit").submit();

});
```

If you don't unbind the `submit` event when you click the button, the submit will just do nothing.

Comment: This code is formated quite badly. It will not work at all. What is `$("form").submit(){ return false; }`?

Comment: @Peter Ajtai; My apologies, I meant to do `$("form").submit(function(){ return false; });`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bit of confusion about propagation here. Event propagation (which can be disabled by [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)) means that events "bubble up" to parent elements; in this case, the click event would register on the form, because it is a parent of the submit button. But of course the submit handler on the form will not catch the click event.

What you are interested in is the default action, which in the case of clicking a submit button is to submit the form. The default action can be prevented by either calling [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or returning false. You are probably doing the latter.

<s>Note that in Javascript functions which do not end with an explicit `return` do still return a value, which is the result of the last command in the function. You should end your click handler with `return;` or `return true;`.</s> I have no idea where I got that from. Javascript functions actually return undefined when there is no explicit return statement.

Comment: Hi Tgr, as mentioned to Peter, I am not really talking about the propagation problem per se, i am more confused because these 2 events are supposed to fire independently (i do not care about the sequence.)

Comment: They are not at all independent. As I tried to explain, the default action of the click event is submitting the form, which causes the submit event. Since you prevent the default action, there is no reason for a submit event to happen.